# Error when converting Results to List for dataSource in UITableView - Realm

Tags: ios, uitableview, realm

I keep getting error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` when using a `List` made out of `Results` as my data source for my tableView.

I know I could use `Results` as my data source, in fact I tried it and it works fine, but I don't want to show the first item in my TableView, that's why I'm converting `Results` to `List`  to be able to remove it from `Results` without having to remove it from `Realm`.

What am I missing here?

Here is the code...

```
var lists : List<ItemList>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    updateLists()
}

func updateLists(){
    let allLists = realm.objects(ItemList.self)

    // Convert Results to List to be able to remove first item
    var lists: List = List(allLists)
    lists.remove(at: 0)
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return lists.count  // error points here
}
```

It shouldn't be nil, here is the output... `print("\(realm.objects(ItemList.self))")`

```
Results<ItemList> (
    [0] ItemList {
        listName = List One;
        createdAt = 2017-05-06 01:12:47 +0000;
        items = RLMArray <0x6180002e4200> (
            [0] Item {
                productName = Bananas;
                createdAt = 2017-05-06 18:23:59 +0000;
            },
            [1] Item {
                productName = Grapes;
                createdAt = 2017-05-07 11:37:33 +0000;
            }
        );
    },
    [1] ItemList {
        listName = List Two;
        createdAt = 2017-05-06 18:16:14 +0000;
        items = RLMArray <0x6180002e4180> (
            [0] Item {
                productName = Apples;
                createdAt = 2017-05-06 18:16:14 +0000;
            },
            [1] Item {
                productName = Oranges;
                createdAt = 2017-05-06 18:16:14 +0000;
            }
        );
    }
)
```

ERROR: Points to numberOfRowsInSection method

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instantiate another instance of lists array inside updateLists() method.
Try fix like this:

```
// Convert Results to List to be able to remove first item
var lists: List = List(allLists)
self.lists = lists
self.lists.remove(at: 0)
```

Comment: Oh, my god, I cannot believe it. Sorry about the stupid question. Thank you for pointing that out.